# a good hex/binary calculator

Tags: gcalctool

Is there an obvious way of shifting numbers in the `gcalc-tool` using an operator, such as `<< or >>` 
 Am I missing an obvious shortcut? 

 Say I want to simply perform `(1<<20)`, how can I do that without the need to shift by 15 and then by 5 using the drop-down buttons?

Alternatively, is there a good hex/binary calculator that you would suggest specifically oriented at hex/binary operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I have seen Gnome Calculator does not have keyboard shortcuts to those functions. Either way [Qalculate](http://qalculate.sourceforge.net/) lets you do exactly that.

[image]

To install either search it in Software Center or using terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qalculate-gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

BASH also supports bitwise operations like bitwise or:

```
$ echo $((1|2|4|8|16))
31
```

Hex and decimal:

```
$ echo $((1|2|4|8|0x10|0x20))
63
```

Zero-prefixed binary output (using BASH for the bitwise or, dc to output its binary, and printf to zero-prefix):

```
$ printf "%08s" $(dc -e "2o  $((1|2|4|8|0x10|0x20)) p")
00111111
```

Good for quick-and-dirty.  man bash